# TypeScript: assigning `Pick<T, K>` to `Partial<T>`

Tags: typescript, generics

In the following example, I can't think of any situation where assigning `Pick<Object, Key>` to `Partial<Object>` would not be sound, therefore I would expect this to be allowed.

Can anyone clarify why it is not allowed?

```
const fn = <T, K extends keyof T>(partial: Partial<T>, picked: Pick<T, K>) => {
    /*
    Type 'Pick<T, K>' is not assignable to type 'Partial<T>'.
        Type 'keyof T' is not assignable to type 'K'.
            'keyof T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
    */
    partial = picked;
};
```

[TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKgGhgaRgUwA8p8wATCGAa3wE8Q4Z0A+ACgAcBDAJygEtOAGwBcMAAo9+QjM2zs+wGmVFiFVDNhzMAlMmYwA3gCgYpmAHoAVCbPpa7fDADkqxRtzMnMPpTAhYnBAQfADmYJwARoKOUCAwUPaOLpICgjJOAHQ2ZraJzjT0jOhePjB+AUGh4VExcQkOzjiZ2TmtTgUMTCWUgcFhkdHxdQAWjqCQUNycfGCwnfVJTdgRAK6wTk0woCuCZDARjjPQnLMCJHsA7nxQwzCcMGR8cHD43KSwECsRCzCd49BTGbrAEzEIwAA+ZRWAFsDtwITAILRYSBBM0cpZzC0uLxUsgYPJFPgyABuIwAXxJQA)

Comment: I find mapped and conditional types usually have strange errors when they still have unresolved type parameters in them. The error is technically right `K` extends `keyof Obejct` so K could be something like `keyof Obejct & { brand: true  }` although the value of that is dubious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@TitianCernicovaDragomir is essentially correct that the compiler generally is unable to do sophisticated type analysis on unresolved generic types.  It does much better with concrete types.  See [Microsoft/TypeScript#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) for a discussion about this with `Pick` and `Omit` with complementary sets of keys.

In these situations the only way to proceed is for you to personally verify that the assignment is sound and then use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) as in `partial = picked as Partial<T>`...

---

... but I wouldn't do that in this case.  The error really is a good one here, although it's hard to see why since you've essentially just overwritten the `partial` variable and done nothing with it within the function scope.  So despite being unsound the code is harmless because it hasn't been allowed to wreak havoc elsewhere.  Let's unchain it by making `fn()` return the modified `partial` variable:

```
const fn = <T, K extends keyof T>(partial: Partial<T>, picked: Pick<T, K>) => {
  partial = picked; // error, for good reason
  return partial; // 
};
```

So, the basic problem is that `Pick<T, K>` is a *wider* type than `T`.  It contains the properties from `T` with keys in `K`, but it is not known *not* to contain properties with keys *not* in `K`.  I mean, a value of type `Pick<{a: string, b: number}, "a">` may well have a `b` property.  And if it does have one, it does not have to be of type `number`.  So it's a mistake to assign a value of type `Pick<T, K>` to a variable of type `Partial<T>`.

Let's flesh this out with a silly example.  Imagine you have a `Tree` interface and an object of type `Tree`, like this:

```
interface Tree {
  type: string;
  age: number;
  bark: string;
}
  
const tree: Tree = {
  type: "Aspen",
  age: 100,
  bark: "smooth"
};
```

And you also have a `Dog` interface and an object of type `Dog`, like this:

```
interface Dog {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  bark(): void;
}

const dog: Dog = {
  name: "Spot",
  age: 5,
  bark() {
    console.log("WOOF WOOF!");
  }
};
```

So, `dog` and `tree` both have a numeric `age` property, and they both have a `bark` property of differing types.  One is a `string` and the other is a method.  Do note that `dog` is a perfectly valid value of type `Pick<Tree, "age">`, but an *invalid* value of type `Partial<Tree>`.  And therefore when you call `fn()`:

```
const partialTree = fn<Tree, "age">(tree, dog); // no error
```

my modified `fn()` returns `dog` as `Partial<Tree>`, and fun begins:

```
if (partialTree.bark) {
  partialTree.bark.toUpperCase(); // okay at compile time
  // at runtime "TypeError: partialTree.bark.toUpperCase is not a function"
}
```

That unsoundness leaked through precisely because `Pick<T, K>` is not known to exclude or otherwise constrain the "unpicked" properties.  You can create your own `StrictPicked<T, K>` in which the properties from `T` not in `K` are explicitly excluded:

```
type StrictPicked<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, K> &
  Partial<Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>>;
```

And now your code is more sound (ignoring weird things like `K` being a branded type like in the [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir))... but the compiler still can't verify it:

```
const fn2 = <T, K extends keyof T>(
  partial: Partial<T>,
  picked: StrictPicked<T, K>
) => {
  partial = picked; // also error
  partial = picked as Partial<T>; // have to do this
  return partial;
};
```

That's still the basic issue here; the compiler can't easily deal with things like this.  Maybe it will someday?  But at least it's not as easily misused on the caller side:

```
fn2<Tree, "age">(tree, dog); // error, dog is not a StrictPicked<Tree, "age">
```

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZmGBeGAeAKgGhgaRgUwA8p8wATCGAa3wE8Q4Z0A+ACgAcBDAJygEtOAGwBcMAAo9+QjM2zs+wGmVFiFVDNhzMAlMmYwA3gCgYMLrwGDkZtfjIBuGAHonBbtxDdscTzADmICBkMNz4nBDgJiH4UACu3IjmUoKOLjCAvBuAEHtGAL72RkZ8YCTccJzA+EyhlcamULTs+KLQ3EV++aacfk0wYLEAtgBG+NwdMIM8VM1QrWDtuQWgkLAz+D3o1da1MPWNogBEAIIQjWD7mFFdPQCMAAy3F6YT3FMw+xD9gVAAFvu5+YViiMyhUYAAREB+QxRMCcfo9FptMZXUR9IYjMbPKisbSiABuID4DgWRiW0BgZEhoghUJQ21h8IOAGV2CAoOdLt1RABWR7jSY46GmUxkkCCfAAOkEkNY+wA6gB5BUAMRgipVAEJ9toxjl-otwOSkpYNmtrAgMNVsPsrvs2Kt8NhKX4dc5XGAQG4PNwCnxGBxJCbqhKsbptsahKbJViJVAQABVdiNbgAYXC+BxqVcIConFoME4sFA-Xk4p2fHhUTShZCsWKFcq+3QDXwAFF3J5RBHBFGQ5NYwmkyM0xBKnxKB7YJx4HXgPxwH89UZdpUmTMFFBVIo7BpcARiKQKNQ6AwmPoUFv1FhcPoAGRRCQWaQAJXwoG4ZFQrcIwEEsTI+CoDQ9CMNeWjYGA+B4iMzDMACZKwAgABM1i7ngRAkOQlDAaeLCsFE3YqIG0gsHy8jbsoMBrq0c6XjuYHMEYuhIPo4bEVYKDkUoWYFoIERep4BHsdYXF2AWlCPskMg8d8nDQTsnqUjs3zjlEoRxAkZjsfkeRGMhlprNatr2laFKQq6aQjN6TqQjA469GyBZUeutG2J+UZGd0dpGEAA)

Comment: As much as your answer makes sense, I still find myself going round in circles when I read the error message provided by TypeScript: `'keyof T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'K', but 'K' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | symbol'.` It would be a massive help if you could update your answer to break down this error message, so I can more easily interpret it in the future? I've seen it in quite a few cases, and every time I find myself confused.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's looking at `Pick<T, K>` as `{[P in K]: T[P]}` and `Partial<T>` as `{[P in keyof T]?: T[P]}` and complaining that the `keyof T` from `Partial` isn't assignable to the `K` from `Pick`.  If `K` is narrower than `keyof T` then you run into the risk of the `bark` issue from above.