# Why Partial works for concrete type but not for subtype in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, extends

I am wondering why it compiles with error.
I guess it should work for subtypes as well as for `Model` type itself.

```js
class Model {
  id!: string;
}

class cls<M extends Model> {
  call (id: string) {
    // got error here (why?)
    this.no({ id }); // Argument of type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<M>'.
    this.yes({ id });
  }

  no (m: Partial<M>) {
    return false;
  }

  yes (m: Partial<Model>) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

[link to testground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiaBvAsAKGtAlogIQBc0EALgE74B2A5gNw4C%20OOokMoEAPLNGQAPCslqIYCFCAB8GHHmBgQaABSEylGgwCU83HmgUAFvggA6WvFXoCiaCx3MDeE2fMBPZBBt2HThQd2AytoVQBbMgAFMCoKfGV%20GT0sF2gqZAoAVypaaAAzZQhkZzw2bECvGAjo2PjEqVRk-UN0zJy86iySwPLyoA)

Comment: [This](https://tsplay.dev/mAv2XW) is the main reason

Comment: @jcalz ok thanks but why `call(id: M['id'])` still is not working?

Comment: Because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56788853/typescript-assigning-pickt-k-to-partialt I think... `{id: M["id"]}` is equivalent to `Pick<M, "id">` which is, unfortunately, not assignable to `Partial<M>` for generic `M`... this is technically correct since a value of type `{id: M["id"]}` might have additional unknown properties which happen to violate `Partial<M>`.  Obviously you can work around these with type assertions, but that's what's going on.